Properties of transformations: translation * rotation * scale
For points in the plane consider the transformations composed of translation * rotation * scale:
$T_{\vec s, \alpha, f}: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2: \vec x \mapsto R_\alpha(\vec x+\vec s)*f$  (first shift, then rotate, then scale uniform by scalar f)
I am wondering if the parameters of this transformation can be uniquely determinded from a set of points $\{\vec x_i, \vec x_i^\prime\}$, where $\vec x_i^\prime=T(\vec x_i)$ for all $i$.
Of course, for one point, it is not unique, because one could just shift it by $\vec x^\prime-\vec x$ or apply some non-trivial scale and rotations and shift.
For two points $T(\vec x_1) = \vec x_1^\prime,\ T(\vec x_2) = \vec x_2^\prime$ , there is:

consider $\vec v = \vec x_2 - \vec x_1, \ \vec v^\prime=\vec x_2^\prime-\vec x_1^\prime$ (connecting vectors)
the rotation is the difference of angles of these connecting vectors, $\alpha = \angle \vec v^\prime - \angle \vec v$
the scale will be the scale of these connecting vectors: $f = |\vec v^\prime|/|\vec v|$
to get the shift, we can rearrange the formula for index 1: $\vec x_1^\prime = T(\vec x_1) = R_\alpha(\vec x_1)*f+R_\alpha(\vec s)*f \Rightarrow \vec s = R_{-\alpha}(\vec x_1^\prime/f-R_\alpha(\vec x_1))$.

Is this correct and is this unique?
(For the case of two points)

Two points is sufficient to determine rotation, translation, and scaling, but if reflection is a possibility, you need a third point to determine whether the orientation is the original or reversed orientation.
